# Shard Map Manager and query node in same DB

Tags: sql-server, azure-elastic-sharding

I'd like to consolidate DBs and have my shard map manager be in the same DB as my head query node.  Following bellow link description. However, when I go to query, I get an error of

"Error accessing the shard map manager database.  Please verify that the shard map manager database is available.  If it is available, please verify that the definition and affiliated credential are correct for external data source ElasticDBQueryDataSrc."

Can someone explain how to do it or refute the Microsoft documentation? Thanks [enter link description here](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/master/articles/sql-database/sql-database-elastic-query-getting-started.md#create-an-elastic-query-database)

Comment: I need to add shards by TenantId , not by range id, How could I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to leverage the split-merge tool to create a new shard. If TenateID is not already a sharding key, then no data movement is necessary. If data movement is necessary then things become a bit more complicated. Please take a look at the following [split-merge tool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-elastic-scale-shard-map-management#adding-a-shard) information.